# Describe Cassandra ColumnFamily

Tags: python, cassandra

I am connecting to a Cassandra database and am trying to find out what attributes an entry in a column family has. I am unable to use the cqlsh command line utility. After creating the connection I have:

```
myCF = ColumnFamily(myConncetion, "user")
for u in myCF.get_range():
    u_item = u[1]
    name = u_item.get('FIRST_NAME')
    print name
```

This prints the names of all users. I would like to know what other attributes besides "FIRST_NAME" a u_item has. Is there a built in function that can describe its attributes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Cassandra are you running?  If you wanted to go through the table programmatically, you could try querying the schema from the system tables:

If you're on Cassandra >= 3.x+:

```
SELECT column_name FROM system_schema.columns 
    WHERE keyspace_name='yourkeyspacename' AND table_name='yourtablename';
```

If you're on Cassandra <= 2.2.x;

```
SELECT column_name FROM system.schema_columns 
    WHERE keyspace_name='yourkeyspacename' AND columnfamily_name ='yourtablename';
```

> How can I execute this Select statement from a python script?

If I'm running on Cassandra 2.2.5, I can take the above code and make it work in a Python script (`cassConnect.py`) like this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

import sys

hostname=sys.argv[1]
username=sys.argv[2]
password=sys.argv[3]
keyspace=sys.argv[4]
table=sys.argv[5]

nodes = []
nodes.append(hostname)

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=username, password=password)
cluster = Cluster(nodes,auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

pStatement = session.prepare("""
    SELECT column_name FROM system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name=? AND columnfamily_name=?;
""")

rows = session.execute(pStatement,[keyspace,table])
for row in rows:
    print row[0]

$ python cassConnect.py 127.0.0.1 aploetz bacon stackoverflow user
email
first
last
username
```

Comment: How can I execute this Select statement from a python script? As I mentioned I cannot use the cqlsh command line utility

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed!

Comment: @TheScendant  Glad I could help!